# Как исключить коммит из истории git?

Tags: git

Вчера в истории появились коммиты которые не должны были попасть в git

Выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось так, что нужно было почистить файлы которые в `.gitignore`, но в тоже время и продолжают трекаться гитом.

Чтоб это сделать выбрали этот метод

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839198/5709159

и действительно все получилось. Но в итоге оказалось, что не все файлы которые были в `.gitignore` на самом деле должны были быть удалены.

Проблема в том, что теперь эти комиты запушены и их нужно удалить.

У кого какие идеи как это можно сделать?

Можно ли как то взять удаленые файлы (они ведь все отмечены в коммите) и вернуть из обратно в историю как новый коммит?

**P.S.** Файлы были в истории, потом их удалили (хотя не нужно было) и запушили в гит. Теперь нужно эти файлы вернуть обратно.

Изменения нужно не просто откатить. А скажем были комиты `A - B - C - D` коммит `A` содержит нужные файлы, далее в коммите `B` эти файлы удаляют далее продолжают работать и делают уже нормальные комиты с нужными имплементациями `C и D` . Что получается. Нам нужно исключить коммит `B` тоесть нам нужно вернуть все файлы которые в нем были удалены из коммита `A`, но так же нам нужно оставить изменения `C и D`. В итоге должно выйти так `A - C - D`. Или можно сделать, что то вроде такого `A - B - C - D - B`

Comment: если это было запушено, то после правки истории Вам нужно будет сделать форсированный пуш. Если Вы работаете не один над репозиторием, то коллегам это может сильно не понравиться

Comment: @KoVadim согласен, но это было только вчера так, что мне кажется, что еще не все успели обновиться. Но в любом случае пока у меня нет идеи как это сделать.

Comment: Вам нужна эта страница документации https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8 - и команда filter-branch. Потом, когда локальная история будет выглядеть красиво, нужно будет сделать форсированный пуш и надеятся, что другие не обидятся

Comment: @KoVadim эта команда похоже может помочь удалить файл(ы) из всех истории. Но мне получается нужно не удалить, а вернуть из обратно. Они были в истории, потом из удалили (хотя не нужно было) и запушили. Теперь их нужно вернуть. Или я не так понял, что делает эта команда?

Comment: она может все делать, то есть, можно каждый коммит модифицировать так как нужно. Но если нужно просто откатить изменения, то это совсем другая задача

Comment: @KoVadim Дополнил вопрос

Comment: я бы открыл git reflog и посмотрел, не осталось ли там ветки в правильном состоянии, перед началом этих всех изменений. А потом просто поменять ветку на правильную и все будет ок. Но это при условии, что никто не запускал git gc или GUI тулу, которая может его запустить (source tree)/

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko я не могу понять нужно ли вам именно переписать историю (т.е. из истории A - B - C - D сделать A - C - D) или вы хотите просто отменить изменение сделанное в комите B (чтоб получилось A - B - C - D - E, где E - изменения обратные B)?

Comment: @RomanKonoval в целом мне кажется, что для меня это не имеет значения. Мне нужны те файлы которые были удалены в коммите В. Я вижу два пути, либо отменить этот коммит, либо взять удаленные файлы (как то) и добавить их снова как новый коммит. Значения не имеет, но мне нужны файлы. Мне кажется, что проще (как то) взять все файлы удаленные и закомитить их как новый коммит

Comment: Можно убирать коммит по его ID. Такой вопрос уже есть на Stackoverflow.

Comment: @FeironoX5 есть сслыка?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740179/Удалить-ненужные-коммиты - Попробуйте это.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vorozhba/b458077f396191a6105cf91e1739a313

Comment: Последний способ удалит все изменения до указанного комита - это совсем не то, что нужно, т.к. потеряются более поздние изменения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой способ отменить изменения сделанные в комите это воспользоваться командой `git revert`:

```
git revert <commit-id>
```

Т.е. если есть история комитов `A - B - C - D`, то после команды:

```
git revert B
```

Будем иметь историю `A - B - C - D - E`, где в комите E - изменения обратные изменениям внесенным комитом B.

Если нужно отменить только часть изменений сделанных в комите, то можно добавить параметр `--no-commit`:

```
git revert --no-commit <B-commit-id>
```

В этом случае изменения комит E не будет создан автоматически, будут сделаны изменения обратные B в рабочей директории, которые можно вручную подправить и дальше уже использовать `git add` и `git commit`.

Comment: Я не уверен, что я правильно понял, `git revert` удаляет только указанный коммит или всю цепочку коммитов до указонного коммита?

Comment: revert не удаляет коммит. Он делает следующее - он берет diff коммита, дальше меняет + на минусы и наоборот. И потом его применяет как коммит. Другими словами - он пытается сделать компенсационные изменения, что бы откатить изменнения, внесенные коммитом.

Comment: @KoVadim прав. Я добавил более подробное объяснение, как работает `revert`.